# How to delete a words with friends account

Tags: words-with-friends

My Words with Friends account got hacked and someone else is starting games and playing current games with all sort of people. How can I delete my account?

I don't want to just remove the app or change my name.  I'd like to actually have the account deleted so that friends that I am already connected to don't get bugged by the hacker.

Does anyone know how to contact their support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Words with Friends player support site [here](https://support.zynga.com/) and search for "Words with Friends" - the link you're using is probably just temporarily broken, but on the support site I've linked you can ask questions or browse existing answers.